# C# delegate casting from MethodInfo.Getmethod()

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing program that makes mathematical operations on functions. I want user to input function so I wrote class which makes scource code with needed method, compiles it and saves method as delegate. This method is passed to constructor of my another class where it is stored in delegate.
The problem is: it doesn't work. InvalidCastException occurs.

(I made it so I don't have to write my own math parser. Expressions such as Math.Pow(x, 2) * Math.Sin(x) should be OK, no need for things like x^2*sin(x) to work)

[Edited]
Now I use

```
Func<decimal, decimal>
```

Where the delegate is passed (to construcor of class Function: public Function(func f, decimal l)):

```
Func<decimal, decimal> function = new Func<decimal, decimal>(MathParser.MakeExpr(inputTextBox.Text));
       
F = new Function(function, l);
```

What generates needed delegate:

```
    using Microsoft.CSharp;
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Furry
    {
        internal class MathParser
        {
            private static string begin =
    @"using System;
    namespace Parser
    {
        public delegate decimal func(decimal x); 

        public static class LambdaCreator 
        {
            public static decimal Create()
            {
        return (x)=>";
            private static string end = @";
            }
        }
    }";
    public static Func<decimal, decimal> MakeExpr(string Expr)
    {
        string middle = Expr;
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, begin + middle + end);
        Type cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Parser.LambdaCreator");
        MethodInfo method = cls.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        Delegate f = method.Invoke(null, null) as Delegate;
        //MessageBox.Show(f.DynamicInvoke(5m).ToString()); doesn't work
        return (Func<decimal, decimal>)f;
    }
}
```

}

Also tried to invoke:

```
Func<decimal, decimal> f = method.Invoke(null, null) as Func<decimal, decimal>;
```

Now FileNotFoundException occurs.
FileNotFoundException: Failed to load file or assembly "file:///C:\Users\Adefe\AppData\Local\Temp\trd2ig0g.dll " or one of their dependencies. The specified file cannot be found.

Comment: The `func` type defined in `begin` isn't the same `func` type which is defined in your C# code. Why not use a type which both can access, such as `Func<decimal, decimal>`?

Comment: Another option is to define your `Create` method as `public static decimal Create(decimal x)` (rather than having it return a delegate), and just invoke it

Comment: None of above works. Decimal function doesn't work at all. FileNotFoundException occurs.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you've tried, otherwise we can't help

Comment: Sorry, it's edited now

Comment: Your defined your `Create` method as `decimal Create()`, yet you're trying to cast its return value to a `Func<decimal, decimal>`. That's a weird incorrect mix of the two separate suggestions I made. If your `Create` method returns a delegate, then its return type should be `Func<decimal, decimal>`: this is currently causing your generated C# code to fail to compile, causing your FileNotFound error. If you change your `Create` method to instead accept a `decimal` and return a `decimal`, then its return type will obviously be `decimal`, so you shouldn't case it to a `Func<decimal, decimal>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
MathParser class:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Furry
{
    internal class MathParser
    {
        private static string begin =
@"using System;
namespace Parser
{
    public delegate decimal func(decimal x); 

    public static class LambdaCreator 
    {
        public static Func<decimal, decimal> Create()
        {
            return (x)=>";
        private static string end = @";
        }
    }
}";
    public static Func<decimal, decimal> MakeExpr(string Expr)
    {
        string middle = Expr;
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, begin + middle + end);
        Type cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Parser.LambdaCreator");
        MethodInfo method = cls.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        Delegate f = method.Invoke(null, null) as Delegate;
        return (Func<decimal, decimal>)f;
    }
  }
}
```